# Almost Sure Convergence (Durrett 2.4.1)

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

> Suppose the $j^{th}$ light bulb burns for an amount of time $X_j$ and
> then remains burned out for time $Y_j$ before being replaced. Suppose
> the $X_j$,$Y_j$ are positive and independent with the $X_j$’s having
> distribution $F$ and the $Y_j$ ’s having distribution $G$, both of
> which have finite mean. Let $R_t$ be the amount of time in $[0, t]$
> that we have a working light bulb. Show that $\frac{R_t}{t}$ →
> $\frac{EX_1}{(EX_1 + EY_1)}$ almost surely.

I have shown that $\frac{R_t}{t}$ is in between by $\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N_t} X_j}{N_t}$ and $1- \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N_t} Y_j}{N_t}$ ; and both these bounds converge almost surely to what we want to prove in the problem. But how do we conclude that $\frac{R_t}{t}$ also does the same?

Comment: The squeeze theorem also works for almost sure convergence, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4156353/does-squeeze-theorem-apply-for-almost-sure-convergence)

Comment: @Lorago, thanks !!