# Show that $(x_{n})_{n}$ is dense in $[0,1]\setminus A$ then it is also dense in $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $B([0,1])$ be the borel set on $[0,1]$ and suppose that $\mu$ is a finite measure on $B([0,1])$. Then, define $A=[0,1]\cap \left \{ x;\mu(\left \{ x \right \})>0 \right \}$. I have shown that if $A$ is countable, then $[0,1]\setminus A$ is a separable metric space (because it is a subset of a separable metric space). Now if $(x_{n})_{n}$ is a dense sequence in   $[0,1]\setminus A$, then I want to show that it is also dense in $[0,1]$. How can I prove it?

Comment: Let $K$ be the limit points of $(x_n)_{n}$ in $[0,1]$, which is in particular closed. If $K\neq [0,1]$, then $U=[0,1]\setminus K$ is open and non-empty. This implies that there is an interval $(a,b)\subset U$ with $a\neq b$. We must have $(a,b)\subset A$, since all the points of $[0,1]\setminus A\subset K$. You already proved that $A$ is countable, but $(a,b)$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $I=(a,b)$ is an open interval in $[0,1]$ then $I \setminus A$ is uncountable so in particular a non-empty open subset of $[0,1]\setminus A$ and so contains some $x_n$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

The complement of a countable subset of $\mathbb R$ is dense, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119379/is-the-complement-of-a-countable-set-in-mathbbr-dense-application-to-conve). Thus, $[0,1]\setminus A$ is dense in $[0,1]$.

The rest follows from the transitivity of the denseness property.